# MySQL where in list but not in temp table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I am considering the following 2 tables

```
|------------|  |-----------|
| user_roles |  |   roles   | 
|============|  |===========|
| user_id    |  | role_id   |
| role_id    |  | code_name |
|------------|  |-----------|
```

I want to get all user_roles where user_id in a given list of user_ids. But I want to exclude all users who have a role with code_name = 'special_role'.

What would be the best way to do this?

For the purpose of an example, lets say I have the following:

```
user_roles:             roles:

| user_id | role_id |   | role_id |  code_name   |
|=========|=========|   |=========|==============|
|    1    |    1    |   |    1    | special_role |
|    1    |    2    |   |    2    | another_role |
|    2    |    2    |   |---------|--------------|
|    3    |    2    |
|---------|---------|
```

My thought was to use temp tables, like:

```
create temporary table if not exists all_user_ids as (
  select ur.user_id as user_id, ur.role_id as role_id
  from user_roles ur
  where ur.user_id in (1,2,3)
);

create temporary table if not exists special_user_ids as (
  select aui.user_id as user_id
  from all_user_ids aui
  join roles r on r.role_id = aui.role_id
  where r.code_name = 'special_role'
);

create temporary table if not exists non_special_user_ids as (
  select aui.user_id as user_id
  from all_user_ids aui
  where aui.user_id not in (special_user_ids.user_id)
);
```

Then for my final result, I could do:

```
select ur.user_id, ur.role_id
from user_roles ur
where ur.user_id in (non_special_user_ids.user_id)
```

But there's got to be a better way?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions - if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
select *
from (
    select ur.*, r.code_name, max(r.code_name = 'special_role') over(partition by user_id) has_special_role
    from user_roles ur
    inner join roles r on r.role_id = ur.role_id
) t
where has_special_role = 0
```

In earlier versions, one method is `not exists`:

```
select ur.*
from user_roles ur
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from user_roles ur1
    inner join roles r1 on r1.role_id = ur1.role_id
    where ur1.user_id = ur.user_id and r1.code_name = 'special_role'
)
```

Comment: we're using MySQL 5.7 :(

Comment: in your "inner join" clause, I believe you mean `on r.role_id = ur1.role_id`, yes?

Comment: @JED: indeed. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just join. This should be pretty fast assuming you have keys set up.

```
SELECT * FROM user_roles JOIN role ON user_roles.role_id = role.role_id 
    WHERE user_roles.user_id IN(1,2,3 ...) AND role.code_name != "special_role"
```

Misunderstood the ask. If you want no users that have a special role at all:

```
SELECT * FROM user_roles WHERE user_id NOT IN(
    SELECT user_id FROM user_roles JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.role_id
        WHERE role.role_code = 'special_role')
    AND user_id IN (1, 2, 3 ...)
```

Comment: With the given example data, your suggestion would give me 3 results [1,2], [2,2], [3,2]. I want to receive only [2,2], [3,2]. Since user 1 has the "special role", I don't want to include any of that user's user_roles.

Comment: Edited with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` and `NOT IN` for the 2 conditions:

```
select *
from user_roles
where user_id in (<list of usr_ids>)
and user_id not in (
  select user_id from user_roles 
  where role_id = (select role_id from roles where code_name = 'special_role')
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/soVXHVoh1M5a4VLYgGcxo1/0).